# How to Read and write on same text file using Perl

Tags: perl, file, hash

I am opening a file in Read Write mode ( +< ) and traversing through each line saving previous line.Based on previous line I am trying to modify current line which doesn't seem to work.

**My INPUTS:**  I have a student hash where name,address and DOB are present. I have a file where student information placed between begin(local or international) and end tags.

Please find below my input txt file:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++ViSHWASCHOOL++++++++++++++++++++++++++
student database system.... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
some text here.... filled with xxx
for school data security ++++++
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


/begin Local
         Karen
         ""
         mothername Mawna
         fathername Gildixon
         total_marks 400 
         percent 90%  /end Local

/begin Local
         John
         ""
         fathername Alister
         mothername Linda
         total_marks 320 
         percent 72%  /end Local        

/begin Local
         Katie
         "24 lenin street florida us"
         mothername Sandra
         fathername Manwel
         total_marks 450 
         percent 95%        /end Local

/begin International
         Boris
         ""
         mothername laumra
         fathername deaol
         total_marks 490 
         percent 98%  /end International

/begin International
         hawo binco
         "honko , china"
         mothername ""
         fathername ""
         total_marks 500 
         percent 100%  /end International
```

**Task:** Now what I want to do is fill all the addresses in the student file where ever it find empty "" just after the student name.preserving all spaces and format of student file as is.

**My Perl Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %student_hash;
my $student_report = "StudentReport.csv";

         %student_hash = (
                'RollNummber1' => {
                                   'studentname' => 'Boris',
                                   'address' => ['Vietnam',
                                                 'local'
                                                ],
                                   'DOB' => '5june2000'

                                   },
                'RollNummber2' => {
                                   'studentname' => 'John',
                                   'address' => [ 
                                                 '4th/floor',
                                                 'Culverdown/Street',
                                                 'WestHam',
                                                 'UK.',
                                                ],
                                   'DOB' => '2feb2000'

                                   },
                'RollNummber3' => {
                                   'studentname' => 'Karen',
                                   'DOB' => '5march2000'

                                  }
               );



my $studentfile = "testfile.txt";
my @studenttype = ('International', 'Local');

foreach my $type (@studenttype) {
      process_studentfile( $type, $studentfile );
   }
print "\nStudent Files are now filled with addresses\n";

sub process_studentfile {

my $type = shift;
my $studentfile = shift;
open(my $file,'+<',$studentfile);

my $previous_line = "";
while(my $current_line = <$file>){
   if($current_line =~ /""/) {
   foreach my $key(%student_hash) {
       foreach my $name(keys %{$student_hash{$key}}) {
            if($previous_line =~ /$student_hash{$key}{'studentname'}/) {
                print $file join(",",@{$student_hash{$key}->{address}});
            }
       }
    }
    $previous_line = $_; 
    }
   }
   close $file;
}
```

**Note:**I tired this in different ways but still fail to complete the task.Can some one please help without using any cpan modules,standard modules are allowed?

Comment: Without using cpan modules, keyboard, and left hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental problem with using `while ( <$fh> )` at the same time as trying to rewrite. Because that `while` is reading chunks of file based on a delimiter `$/`. But files work in *bytes*.

from [`perldoc open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> You can't usually use either read-write mode for updating textfiles, since they have variable-length records. See the -i switch in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for a better approach.

So if you write a different length line, everything goes a bit baffy. It just doesn't work very well for text files, because you have variable length "records".

You can use `seek` to navigate around the file, but bear in mind that you're essentially doing overwrites on a per byte (character) basis.

Or just use a temp file and copy it over your source when you're done. This is what `-i` does. (Which also means you've a much lower risk of corrupting your data, because you can bail out gracefully if there's a problem)

Comment: Since, I am perl basic user I am unable to understand the concept clearly. You asked me to use temp file so that means i have read line by line from input file and copy it to output file (except when encoountered the "" i can replace with name?) isit? I shall try this now.Thanks

Comment: The long and short of it is - you cannot do what you want with `+<` because it's a text file. So write your output to a new file, and when you're done, copy it over the original.

Comment: ok Sobrique I am trying that now.I am copying line by line(only editing the required line) from input file to output file.

Comment: In internet I found some complicated code where they are using tempfile(UNLINK=>1) . If I want to understand this concept can you please refer me to any good reference or website. where they explain in easy way please?

Comment: Don't need to get that complicated. Just `open ( my $output, '>', "new_file.txt" ) or die $!;` then instead of `print $file ...` you can `print {$output} ....` Once you're done, copy it over the original.

Comment: Yes I tried the following open(my $FILE,'<',$studentfile);
open(my $output,'>',"outputfile.txt");

while(<$FILE>){
if($_ =~ /""/) {
print {$output} "I am empty" ;
}
else 
{
 print {$output} $_ ;
}
}
close($FILE);
close($output);      but the formatting has changed.

Comment: You may be missing line feeds in that case. Hard to say based on content in comments.

Comment: Ya it came to normal when I used the following                                      if($_ =~ /""/) {
my $replace = $_;
$replace =~ s/""/"I am empty"/;     but the actual hash thing i have to do but no problem i shall try that...thanks for your help

Comment: hash thing means.... I have to save the previous line of file then compare with an element in hash then if current line is "" I have to finally get the an other element from hash and insert it in text file. (I have put this requirement in my question). I shall try that now.

Comment: It's because your `while` loop is getting `\n` as part of the line. So when you `print` it there's a line feed. But if you print `"I am empty"` there is no linefeed. But you don't need to use `$replace` - ` s/""/"I am empty"/;` will modify `$_`  by default and then you can just print it.

Comment: Don't change your question - ask a new one. But that's pretty easy - you can use a hash element in the RHS of a replace.

Comment: No I am not changing the question that is what I am after. I have now accomplished my task (I have traversed through hash and used the regex with replace). Thanks a lot.